# How to find the city name not starting and ending with a vowel

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels and do not end with vowels. The result cannot contain duplicates.

At first I tried this:

```
select distinct CITY 
from STATION 
where (CITY NOT LIKE 'A%' 
  or CITY NOT LIKE 'E%' 
  or CITY NOT LIKE 'I%' 
  or CITY NOT LIKE 'O%' 
  or CITY NOT LIKE 'U%')
and (CITY NOT LIKE '%a' 
  or CITY not like '%e'  
  or CITY not like '%i' 
  or CITY not like '%o' 
  or CITY not like '%u');
```

But I did not get the right answer so searched and code the following code which also does not give the right answer:

```
select distinct CITY 
from STATION 
where regexp_like(lower(CITY),'^[^aeiou].');
```

I expect that only those city names which both start and end with a vowel should not be displayed but in the first query all the city names are being displayed and in the second one all the city names starting with a vowel are not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little easier to read would be:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  CITY 
    FROM STATION 
    WHERE  SUBSTR(CITY,1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
    AND SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Note the `-1` in the second `WHERE` clause which tells Oracle to search from the end of the string.

Comment: You can use `upper(city)` to cover upper cases also.

Answer (score 2):

Your first query would be correct if you used `AND` rather than `OR`.

You might find it the logic simpler as:

```
where not (city like 'A%' or city like 'E%' or . . . ) and
      . . .
```

By the rules of logic, this is equivalent to:

```
where city not like 'A%' and city not like 'E%' and . . . ) and
      . . .
```

As for the regular expression, it has only the comparison at the beginning of the string:

```
where not regexp_like(lower(city), '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$')
```

Comment: can you please explain what the second query does?

Comment: Isn't there a smaller query to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from  station where regexp_like(city, '^[^EUIOA].*[^euioa]$');
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct city from station
where left(city,1)in ('a','e','o','i','u');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There are 4 approach to achieve what you are trying to achieve.
1. In your first query change the or condition to and Condition
2. For the regex add comparison to end of string, currently it has only at beginning of string. 
        regexp_like(lower(city), '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$')
3. use substring to check for the first and last value of the string
        SELECT DISTINCT  CITY 
        FROM STATION 
        WHERE  SUBSTR(CITY,1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')
        AND SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U');
4. You can fetch the first and last letter of the city from table station and then check them against vowels using if condition and if there are no vowels you can return the value.
Easiest and better approach would be 3 and 2.